# Calculate the limit of a the following expression

Tags: limits

I'd like to know how to calculate the following:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\log\left(\left(1+(\exp(2x)-1)^2\right)\right)^2.
$$

Unfortunately, I'm not even sure where to begin with calculating this expression, other than just asking Wolfram Alpha. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm perhaps a variable change could help? Something like
$$
x = \frac{1}{2}\ln(t+1)
$$
and then instead of $x \to \infty$ you can look at $t \to \infty$ ... I dunno, just a thought.

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks!  In fact, I think that works - you can then use L'Hopital's rule to figure out the limit of log(1+t^2)/log(1+t). Well spotted!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I used Matti P.'s suggestion and it worked.

Set $x=\frac{1}{2}\log(t+1)$, then you get

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{-2}\log(1+(\exp(2x)-1))^2=\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{4\log(t^2+1)^2}{\log(t+1)^2}.
$$

Then using L'Hopital's rule,

$$
\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{4\log(t^2+1)^2}{\log(t+1)^2}=\lim_{t \to \infty}\left(\frac{2t(t+1)}{1+t^2}\right)^2=4^2=16.
$$

Thanks!